# Node child.exec working but child.spawn not

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm trying to work with Child Spawn (not working) instead of Exec (working). My Exec code provides me with console output, I see nothing if I run my child spawn code, how can I get console output using Child Spawn:

Here is my working exec code:

```
   var exec = require('child_process').exec,
       child;

   child = exec('myProgram --version', {},
   function (error, stdout, stderr) {
       console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
       console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
       if (error !== null) {
           console.log('exec error: ' + error);
       }
   });

   child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
       console.log(data.toString()); 
   });

   child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
       console.log('stderr: ' + data);
   });
```

Here is my non-working attempt at using spawn:

```
   var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

   var spawnchild = spawn('myProgram', ['--version']);

   spawnchild.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
       console.log('stdout: ' + data);
   });
   spawnchild.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
       console.log('stdout: ' + data);
   });
```

Comment: Next time something doesn't work as you expect, I'd recommend reviewing the documentation for it and ascertaining that you have the correct syntax before asking for help.

Comment: By editing your question, you just made the only answer to your question invalid. It's poor practice to do that.

Comment: Does your edit really reflect your problem? I.e are you having this problem even when using the code in your updated question?

Comment: Yes it does reflect the problem, I get console output on the exec code but I do not on the spawn using the code in my updated question, this is the question I am trying to get help with.

Comment: Ok. Then according to the documentation your code should work..

Comment: Is the process erroring? Try adding `spawnchild.on('error', function(err) { console.log(error); })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a 'close' event handler for `spawnchild`, you will see a non-zero exit code. The reason for this is that the first argument for `spawn()` differs from that of `exec()`. `exec()` takes the full command line string, whereas `spawn()` has just the program name/path for the first argument and the second argument is an array of command line arguments passed to that program.

So in your particular case, you'd use:

```
var spawnchild = spawn('myProgram', ['--version']);
```

Comment: I made this change, and updated my original question to include it. However, this did not answer my question, as there is still no logged output when I run via the spawn whereas there is if I use exec.

Comment: Did you verify the exit code is non-zero by adding a 'close' event handler and checking the arguments passed to it?

Comment: I had omitted this code as I thought it was irrelevant, but I have had this all along, and it provides no console log either:  spawnchild.on('close', function(code) {console.log('closing code:' + code);});

Comment: That probably means the process isn't exiting. Out of curiousity, what node version are you using?

Comment: node -v return v0.12.7, I checked node website says there is versions 4+, 5+, am I running an ancient version perhaps? I'm installing nvm now to see if I can update.

Comment: same issue on 5.5.0, I'll dig into it and mark the question as answered, thanks.